# Deletion of file in .git folder

Tags: git

I have unintentionally deleted a file in the .git folder. The repository seems to still work (commit, push, pull, ... are working without problems).

Could a deletion of a file inside the .git folder affect the files outside this folder?
Could the deletion undo some changes in the repository files?

Comment: @Yatin I believe the question is not about regular tracked files, but about intrinsic files of `.git` directory

Comment: Deletion of a file inside of the `.git` folder shouldn't immediately affect any files outside of that folder. Depending upon what file was deleted, it might affect repository status information about certain file(s) when you do a `git status`, for example. There are a lot of different files under `.git` (config, etc). If your commit, push, pull, etc work, then your config seems Ok. You don't know what file you deleted?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After the deletion I have committed, pushed and pulled the repository. Could it have affected the files outside the git. folder?

Comment: If the question is whether you may have accidentally lamed your repository: Yes, of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore a deleted folder in a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875205/restore-a-deleted-folder-in-a-git-repo)

Answer (score 4):

> Could a deletion of a file inside the .git folder affect the files outside this folder?
> could the deletion undo some changes in the repository files?

It really depend on what exactly was deleted.
Deleting `.git/index` for instance is actually not critical, and would for GIt to rebuild automatically said index.

To be on the safe side, I would simply:

- rename my current repo folder in `myrepo.old`
- re-clone my repository in my existing folder `myrepo`
- resume my work

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will follow what you have recommmended.

Comment: @Simone Good call: that is the safest approach.

Answer (score 2):

> Could a deletion of a file inside the .git folder affect the files outside this folder?

No, git won't touch the working directory files unless you tell it to.

> Could the deletion undo some changes in the repository files?

Yes. If you delete a reference in .git/refs you will lose that branch or tag, but the commit it points to will still be there and you can recover its location with `git reflog`.

If you delete a hook in .git/hooks that hook is gone.

If you delete an object file that could be the content of a file, directory, or commit. This would leave you with a corrupted history. `git fsck` will check the integrity of your repository. If you have a remote repository, you should be able to use it to replace the missing object.

If you delete .git/index you will lose your staged changes. You can re-add them.

See the [Git Internals chapter of the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) for more detail.