# Will a folder be deleted entirely if it was deleted in a git repository and the user selects "Discard all changes" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If a user selects to "Discard All Changes", will this restore a deleted folder in Git for the working tree or will it delete the folder entirely?

Comment: That sounds like something that you could experiment with and observe what happens, and thus learn more directly than having someone describe it to you.

Comment: Easy to try on a test repo. What happens?

Comment: got it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I was concerned that if I ran the "Discard All Changes" command, my folder would be deleted entirely. I thought that was strange considering that if you visit a single file that was deleted in the folder, VS Code gives the option of restoring that file, but I wanted to undo the entire folder deletion. Since I didn't stage or commit the changes after I deleted the folder, I was able to revert the change in my working tree by running the following command:

```
git checkout -- path/to/folder
```

That command allows a user to revert changes that have not been indexed or added to the staging area.

I found this helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875442/10860528