# Files lost but commit exists

Tags: git

I had a weird experience with git right now, I had a commit which was done more than one week ago, I store my repository in bitbucket, if I run the git log command, I can see the commit that I did, but the actual files included in that commit were lost. This is the second time that I have experienced it, the first was when I thought I wasn't able to commit that changes and lost it accidentally, but now after checking my log those two commits exists. Any idea why this happened?

Also please note that if I checkout to that specific commit, the files will show. But when I go back to my latest commit, the files were gone. I know haven't removed those.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to add the files to the staging area before committing?

Comment: I agreen with @Martin, this is very common

Comment: I don't think so, if I checkout to that specific commit, the files will show. But when I go back to my latest commit, the files were gone. I know haven't removed those.

Comment: Can you try running `git log -1 --stat -- <the file that's missing>` to see what the last commit involving that file is and include the command and the output in your question.

Comment: @cyphar, tried your suggestion, after running that command, nothing showed. Maybe I just need to create that migration again. Thanks

Comment: Did you do this in a separate branch / have you rebased and removed that commit from your history? Can you *from the current branch you're in* see the commits that modified the file in `git log --stat`?

Comment: @cyphar, yes I did this on a separate branch and I had never rebased or removed that commit from my history. If I run that command, I could not see any modification of that file and also I could not remember a scenario where I modified that file yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . Maybe I just need to create that migration again

You can restore at any time (like in your current HEAD) those file with:

```
git checkout <acommit>-- <file_path>
```

See more at "[Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/953481/6309)".

A `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` helps pinpoint the commits with deleted files.

Comment: In *extreme* situations, you can also use `git reflog`.

Comment: @cyphar yes, when the commit is lost. But here, that doesn't seem to be the case: the commit is visible, and accessible from HEAD.

Comment: That worked, thanks @vonC, before posting this question here I already did the git reflog and tried to merge that commit to my HEAD but replied "Already up to date". Thanks for that solution by the way.

Comment: @JCS yes, if git considered the branch has "already merged", it would have answered that. The checkout is more direct.

Comment: @vonC, sorry, but I don't get it, it says "already up to date" maybe because there is no missing commit? Yet the file that I created was missing even though I haven't modified or deleted it.

Comment: @JCS so `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` returns nothing? (when done in the current branch, or from that other branch?)

Comment: @vonC, it returns my commit log, what puzzles me is that the file went missing without deleting or modifying it. I'll review my log and see where I made a mistake. Thanks a lot