# Revert mistakenly deleted(only) files(many) in Git

Tags: git, git-bash

I mistakenly deleted a lot of files from my workspace, i also have a lot of modified files. How do i revert only the deleted files(and not the modified ones) in one go?

```
deleted:    src/main/content/jcr_root/components/mega-menu/directives/dropdown.js
deleted:    src/main/content/jcr_root/js/components/mega-menu/directives/sub-menu.js
deleted:    src/main/content/jcr_root/js/components/mega-menu/mega-menu-module.js
deleted:    src/main/content/jcr_root/js/components/mobile-menu.js
modified:   src/main/content/jcr_root/js/components/product-list.js
modified:   src/main/content/jcr_root/js/components/product-shipping.js
modified:   src/main/content/jcr_root/js/components/reward-category.js
```

I tried this in one of my local feature branches: `git reset HEAD \*` and then `git checkout --`, but this seems to revert both deleted and modified ones.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git

Comment: yep, this works for a single file, in my case i have many deleted, i'll have to run that command several several times!

Comment: And this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository

Comment: As an aside: Git works best when your commits are small and have one logical unit of change in then; it seems to me like your current commit may have been too large/too much in one go to begin with (of course, it's hard to tell without actually knowing the commit).

Comment: @MicroVirus I have close to 10 files which have been modified and ready to be committed and more than 20 files which have been mistakenly deleted. All of them across varied folders.

Comment: @hypeJunction  Second link didnt work out either.

Comment: Have you tried all suggestions from 2nd links? I would suspect this answer should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4332209/677409

Comment: Starting from this commit and a clean working directory (`git stash` if necessary), maybe you can use a `git reset --mixed` followed by a `git rm -- *` to get all the removed files in the staging area, then commit that, then add all modified files, commit, then on your main branch just cherry-pick that modified commit. I haven't tried this, though.

Comment: @hypeJunction buddy, u saved my day, that command worked. Thanks.

Comment: @MicroVirus Thanks for your suggestions as well.