# Git undo deleted files after commit and push

Tags: git

I deleted some **uncommitted** class and ı committed all files and **pushed**.
I don't know how can I fix that problem.
Please help me. My important classes are lost. I tried some git command but I didn't fix.
I used ;

- git stash
- git hard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: I have already tried this solution. But ı didn't fix @ZimSystem

Comment: Unfortunately the files are gone, do you have backup?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not a situation Git can help you with.  If the file you deleted had not ever been committed, then *by definition* Git doesn't know anything about it, and can't help you recover it.

To avoid this situation in the future, I recommend you Commit Early, Commit Often.  You can always squash commits together later if you want a cleaner history, but creating WIP commits allows you to roll back easily if you make a mistake.

If you have accidentally deleted a file that *had* been committed, then you can restore it as described in [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/953481/2747593).

Comment: thanks for answer. unfortunately, I lost my files :(

Comment: @CemDırman: Yep, sorry about that. Be sure to [accept my answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as this indicates to others that your problem is solved, and also gives you 2 rep! (You can also [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it if you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).)