# GIT: Get Latest of a specified file?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I want to be able to revert 1 file when using GIT [w/Visual Studio]. So for example a file is deleted on the local drive [but still listed in the Solution/Project]. I want to be able essentially right-click the file in the VS Proj and do a, "Get Latest". I've seen this sort of functionality in other SCCS. Is there a set of GIT commands to do this? I do NOT want all the files just a specified one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you deleted on local dirve but still shows in VS are the **changes not staged for commit,** so any one of the below commands can work:

```
git checkout -- .
git reset --hard HEAD
```