# how to bring back a file that is deleted and committed but still present in the branch on git hub

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

I have 7 files on my git hub branch. i deleted 4 of them and made commit, but did not push. Now, I want those 4 deleted files back. other branch have same data and i tried merging, it says ' branch is updated ' but wont show those 4 files. I tried pull, and there is no help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get back those files:

1) if it's your recent commit then you simply reset its to get back your files.
`git reset HEAD~1`

2) if its older commit then you can revert it by

`git revert your_deleted_branch_commit_hash`

Let me know if it resolved the issue

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout origin/my-branch-name -- ./path/to/deleted/file`

Answer (score 0):

You could find the commit when the file was deleted (it will log all deleted files and commits):

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

And then checkout the file:

```
git checkout <commit>~1 <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands if you have not pushed yet.

If you want your changes in staging area (ready to commit) use

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

This will remove your commit which is not pushed and put the changes in staging. if your remove the changes with commit use hard as an option

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```