# GIT: Can you recover the most recent working version of files after accidently committing and pushing their deletion?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Sourcetree with git and for some reason it decided to stage my changed files as to delete instead of just updating them.  I didn't catch this error until after I committed and pushed.  I then realized all my files were missing.  Can I recover these files?

To be clear, I do not want to revert back to the previous commit's file version.  I want to have the files in the states they were when git deleted them so my work is not wasted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: @phd that will recover a file from a previous commit, but as noted I'm hoping there's a way to recover the file that had changes after that commit that was accidently deleted.

Comment: Git itself won't delete your work-tree files (well, except for `git clean`...), but it also does not *save* them anywhere. What it saves are staged files and committed files. Staged files that were not actually committed can sometimes be recovered via `git fsck --lost-found` (they show up as "dangling blob" and are copied into the lost+found dir, with hash IDs for names; you will have to reconstruct the names). If the content was never staged, you're out of luck.

Comment: @torek I'm starting to wonder if Sourcetree GUI runs git clean when committing or pushing, because it definitely deleted the files (I never would have).  Which would be a little scary... I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you never commited the changes to `git` it cannot help you.

But most IDEs (assuming that you use one) have their own change history. E.g.: `eclipse` creates a "safepoint" each time you safe a file.

So you could recover the files state from the commit before the delete:

```
git checkout [commit_before_delete] path/to/your/file
```

And then used your IDE to get the latest saved version back. In `eclipse` this would be *replace with local history* where you get a list of available file versions labeled with the safe timestamp.