# Is "git restore <file>" the same as "get checkout -- <file>"?

Tags: git

The new command, `git restore <file>` does not seem to have much documentation yet.  Does it do exactly the same thing as `git checkout -- <file>`?

I do not understand the explanation of the new commands in the release notes.

In Git 2.23 Release Notes:

- Two new commands "git switch" and "git restore" are introduced to
  split "checking out a branch to work on advancing its history" and
  "checking out paths out of the index and/or a tree-ish to work on
  advancing the current history" out of the single "git checkout"
  command.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt

## Edit1

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/2.23.0

Comment: Maybe this answer to [Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository/57809290#57809290) will help.  And maybe it won't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The Q is about command [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). Please remove your comment.

Comment: @phd: No!  Why should I?  The answer I point at is explicitly discussing `git restore`, even if the question as a whole is not (mainly because `git restore` wasn't around when the question was asked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no additional options, yes:

```
git restore <filename>
```

and:

```
git checkout -- <filename>
```

are synonymous.

If you add options to the `git restore`, then no, they're no longer synonymous. You can add options to the `git checkout` which also break this particular pairing.  There are some additional modes in which `git restore` and `git checkout` are synonymous, but there are a few `git restore` operations that have no corresponding `git checkout` command.  For instance:

```
git restore --source HEAD --staged --worktree <filename>
```

means the same thing as:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <filename>
```

but:

```
git restore --source HEAD^ <filename>
```

(which extracts the `HEAD^` variant of the given file to the work-tree without touching the index) cannot be reproduced through `git checkout`.