# GIT file author metadata for deleted and re-added file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a basic doubt on GIT concepts.

- I have a branch `master` and another branch called `feature`.
- I am working on `feature` branch. I deleted 10 existing files which originally was added by some other author and committed the changes to `feature` branch.
- I added back 4 of the deleted files and committed these changes as well to my `feature` branch.
- I create a pull request for `feature` branch to `master`. In the diff in pull request with `master`, as expected I see 6 files deleted.

My question is, now if the pull request is merged to `master`, would GIT show history of 4 files which has been re-added as added by me or the original author?

Comment: Git doesn't have file history. Git commits *are* history. Asking for the history of a file tells Git: *look at the commit history; see which commits touched the file; with `--follow`, guess at any rename operations.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show those files with the current history they have from `feature` branch:

```
git log --pretty='%an %ad -- %cn %cd' -- aRe-AddedFile
```

Provided you have re-added the file with the exact same content and name ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/953481/6309)), Git will follow that file history from feature branch.

Once the PR is merged, GitHub will show the last commit for that file as part of master history: you would be the author.
As part of the merge commit representing that merged PR, the feature branch history would show the origin author.