# Restore file from git repository using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, delete-file

I have deleted files in my project, committed that and done other commits since then.

Now I need about 15 of those files. There are answers (like [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository/1113140)) on how to do this using git command line.

How can I do the same thing in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: There are no more efficient way than git command. Let's do it by command line interface. You should add more information or edit it for clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way for both situations, either knowing the deleting commit or not even knowing it.

**Case 1:** Let's start with the easier one, where I do know the commit:

1. In "Version Control > Log" view select the commit (search box helps to find it)
2. In box on right hand side (file tree) select all files to recover
3. Right-click and "Revert selected changes"

**Case 2:** Now if I don't know the deleting commit I can either try to narrow the commit log down using the "Paths" filter option. Or I can run these shell commands to get the exact commit (and search that in git log):

1. List all deleted files in repo: `git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete`
2. Find deleting commit for one of those files: `git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- [deleted-filename]`
3. Continue with steps of Case 1 above

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ's Local history module [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) should help you solve your problem. As long as you haven't invalidated caches or installed a new version of the IDE, it should have a revision of before you deleted the files.

(It also has a retention period for revisions, so I hope you didn't delete the files too long ago)

Answer (score 0):

Finding past deleted files is not proposed natively in IntelliJ IDEA, and the local history might not have always those files memorized.

That means you need to [configure a `git bash` terminal in IDEA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000716044-Intelli-IDEA-opens-git-bash-in-a-separate-window-than-the-IDE-), that you can call on:

[image: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/iyR-p8G0kk2P9HahxoUAwQ.png]

Using:  `c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`