# I accidentally deleted some local files in my git repository

Tags: git

I have a folder which is my git local repository, and there are two folders in it the **web folder** and **backend folder**.

I ran this command `git rm -r -f  web` and then all my files inside the web folder were gone, and now I can't find it, I tried to look for it in the trash, but the files aren't there, is there a way I can go back in time and restore all the files?

Comment: may be you can pull from remote repository

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I don't have the files in a remote repository D:

Comment: You can use reset hard to get your files back

Comment: Were the files in the "web" directory ever committed to git?

Comment: @shoover no, the problem was that I was trying to commit the web folder, but for some reason I sent the web folder empty to my github, so I was like what? I hadn't even used some kind of remove command before, then I ran the command that I told above and all the files are gone of my folder

Answer (score 0):

This command will help you to retrieve your previous commit,

```
git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- "$file")^ -- "$file"
```

Comment: When I try to run this command, it says 'fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths
fatal: invalid reference: ^'

Comment: There has been a similar question, check it out, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository?rq=1)