# How to recover deleted files in GIT?

Tags: git

I've initiated new local git repository and added some files but there were some files that shouldn't be, so I typed `git reset --hard` and then all added files disappeared. 
I haven't done any commit on this repository yet.
There is any way to recover my files? I tried to `git checkout .` and `git checkout <filename>` but both returns `error: pathspec '' did not match any file(s) known to git`.

Comment: look at this it might helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113140/10681908

Comment: But I've not done any commit on this repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+hard+reset

Answer (score 0):

- Since you not commit any file, So you not able to recover that file.
- Solutions is that you recover file from recycle bin / trash. if you delete from bin also. Then use third party tool like EaseUs.

Comment: Does git actually send files to the bin? I thought it just deleted them, no?

Answer (score 0):

try this and its work works only if files have not committed and pushed, once i have same problem it worked for me

```
git checkout your-deleted-file-path
```

Comment: OP already tried `git checkout .`