# How to find a file in a git repo that was lost

Tags: git, git-log

There was once a file in our repo that had some content we need to retrieve. There's too many logs to go one by one. So I was thinking we could run a command to list the files that were created and their commit hash. How can you do that?

- List all files created for every commit in a repo.
- Include the commit hash and file name.

Then I can just checkout that commit and see the file. Alternatively, if you know how to list what commits had the certain file, that would be even better. The file is `foo.md` let's say. Then I could checkout the last commit of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- there is built cmd in [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)

```
git ls-files -d, --deleted         show deleted files in the output
```

- [Use git log --diff-filter=D --summary to get all the commits which have deleted files and the files deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953573/15073910)

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary --pretty=format:"%h" --stat
```

it prints

```
5d07713
 test2 | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 test2
```

Comment: This doesn't list all historically deleted files... My file was deleted at some point in the history, I don't know where.

Comment: @alien which cmd did you type in, git rm or just rm -r ?