# How to unstage files on git using cli using git restore?

Tags: git

I tried the same on my terminal (on linux ubuntu) following this video (timestamp 1:02:34)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JJ101D3knE&t=2488s

[This is what it looks like on my terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpuKz.png)

I don't understand what's wrong because even my git version is the latest one I could download

Please help me out.

Comment: `git restore` was introduced in Git v2.23.0. You're on v2.7.4, which is 16 minor versions behind. The latest release is v2.31.0

Answer (score 1):

`git restore` was introduced in [Git v2.23.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/2.30.0).

You're on v2.7.4, which is 16 minor versions behind.

The latest release by the time of writing this is [v2.31.0](https://git-scm.com/downloads). 
Which means you have to update your git version.

---

If you can't update your version for any reason, you can make a handy alias:

```sh
git config alias.restore '!f() { git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- $1)~1 -- $(git diff --name-status $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- $1)~1 | grep '^D' | cut -f 2); }; f'
```

and use it nearly the same way

```sh
git restore yourFile
```

Credits to [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14922749/7575111).

Answer (score 0):

Your Git version is too old.  The "restore" command was added in version `2.23`.  You are running version `2.7`.

You are probably not able to upgrade to a newer version because you are pulling from an older Linux distribution.  I would suggest that you find a way to install a later Git via some other mechanism than what you are currently using to keep your Git up to date.

I believe that the following commands should let you install a more recent version via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

I got this from the post I give below.  It appears to be a question and answer for the same problem you are having. You should check it out for yourself.

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/568591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-git-with-apt